# Isdigit() not working for values in range of 48- 58 in C

Tags: c

I am trying to create program which checks if input from user is a number. This works fine for all of the number and charatcers entered, except for numbers in range of 48 to 57. I've been looking through StackOverflow forum and could not find the answer. Could you please advise, what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(){
    int tab[100];
    int input;
    int index = 0,count=0;
    printf("Podaj liczby:\n");
    do{
        scanf("%i", &input);
        if(!isdigit(input)){
            if(input!=0){
                tab[index] = (int)input;
                index++;
            }
        }else{
            printf("Incorrect input");
            return 1;
        }
    }while(input!=0 && index<100);

    if(index<2){
        printf("not enough data available");
        return 2;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <index; i++){
        count = 0;
        for(int j = i+1;j< index; j++){
            if((tab[i] == tab[j]) && tab[i]!=0) {
                count++;
                tab[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        if(count>0){
            printf("%i ",tab[i]);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 48 to 57 is `'0'` to `'9'` in ASCII. Passing integer input to `isdigit` looks unusual. How do you define "works"?

Comment: `Podaj liczby` -> `Enter the numbers` (Google translation)

Comment: In the English language, a "digit" is one of the following: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.  A combination of digits is most certainly ***not*** a digit, it is a ***number***.  What you are scanning in is `int` numbers.  The `isdigit()` function accepts single `char` digit.  So, nothing of what you are doing makes sense or has the slightest chance of working, and your terminology is so wrong that we cannot even tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: Even if I change input to char type same happens.
By "my code works", I mean that it is compliling without any errors or warnings. Morover, at my university, we are using application to check correctness of programs we have created(multiple test are run, created by our profesors). My program has passed all of these tests, with multiple kind of variables - however when number is provided from range 48 to 57, it is not working correctly. Instead of saving variable in array it's printing out "Incorrect input" error, which should be printed only when input is not digit.

Comment: @MikeNakis The argument of [`isdigit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) is `int`. Passing `int` to `isdigit()` is quite natural and no warnings should be given for that. One reasonable usage is passing return value of [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) (which is also `int`).

Comment: @MikeCAT I'd think `unsigned int` would be better as `isdigit()` expects to be passed an `unsigned char`, but you're correct in implying the passing of a integer type to `isdigit()` is not the source of the problem here.

Comment: @AndrewHenle What `isdigit()` (and other functions in `ctype.h` that takes `int`) accepts are not only values in range of `unsigned char` but also `EOF`. `EOF` is a negative value, so I don't think `unsigned int` is better.

Comment: @MikeNakis If the `scanf()` actually reads the string "48" from the user, the `int` value read should cause `isdigit()` to return a non-zero value.

Comment: @MikeCAT Doh!  Yes, you're right.  It's too early on a Saturday morning here...

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks, I removed my comments about the lack of warnings.

Comment: This input loop is completely incorrect.  Check the behavior when the input stream consists of a non-digit character.  (IOW, try `echo x | ./a.out`).   This is not a correct use of `scanf`.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>    scanf("%i", &input);
> ```

`scanf` with the format `%i` converts its input to an integer. If the user presses <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> Enter, that makes the `scanf` call equivalent to `input = 42`.

If the input can't be converted to an integer, `scanf` returns `EOF` and doesn't set `input`. Since you don't check the return value of `scanf`, your program continues with an indeterminate value in `input`. (In theory that's undefined behavior, but in practice your program will run with whatever happened to be in the memory location of `input`.)

> ```
>    if(!isdigit(input)){
> ```

This tests whether the number `input` is the numerical code of a digit character. In practice, the correspondence between characters and their numerical codes on your computer is ASCII, so digits occupy the range from 48 to 57 inclusive. So the body of this `if` clause only runs if `input` is not between 48 and 57.

I have no idea why you'd do that. If you meant to check whether the input is valid, check the return value of `scanf`. If you thought you were checking the first character of the input, then 1. no you aren't, you're checking the result of the conversion, you can't access the raw input from the user; and 2. you'd only be checking one character anyway so your check couldn't possibly be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `if(!isdigit(input))` clause is checking whether `input` is a digit, and it jumps to the `else` part if it is.  So, if this was ever going to work, you would have to get rid of the '!' operator.

Which leaves us with the next problem: you are using `scanf()` to read `int`s. There is no more checking to be done to see whether an `int` is a number. An `int` is already a number.

But what you do, is that you treat the `int` as a `char` and pass it to `isdigit()`, which will of course only succeed if the `char` is between `0` and `9`, which corresponds to `int` numbers between `48` and `57`.  So, only these numbers succeed, and then you negate the result of `isdigit()`, so you think that only these numbers fail.

Long story short: quit checking whether your numbers are numbers, they are already numbers.